# Extract a substring from string

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a particular pattern of string

```
page0001
page0002
.
.
.
pageMN23
pageMN24
.
page0100
page0101
```

and so on

I have to remove "page" and zero's after that and then pick up the page number from that.
and stroe that value. Here it will return both integer and string value for example "3","4" ,"MN23", MN24".
What can be used so that correct value return and it get store in correctly.

Comment: simply `str.replaceAll("page0","").split(" ")`?

Comment: Doesn't replaceAll accept a regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
test = test.replace("page", "");        
int x = Integer.parseInt(test);
```

Just replace all the occurrences of "page" with an empty string, then `Integer.parseInt()` takes care of the rest.

Comment: If performance is an issue, you could equally use `test = test.substring(4);`.  Less self-documenting though.

Comment: Thank you for support. But i have one more concern related to your answer. Here you have mentioned Integer variable to hold parsed value of "test". But few pages contain string  for example "pageMO12". what can be done in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    String test = "page0100";
    boolean flag = false;
    int pageNo;
    try {
        test = test.replaceAll("page0*", ""); //Note the meta character * after 0. It removes all zeros exists after `page` string and before any non zero digit.
        pageNo = Integer.parseInt(test);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // If NumberNumberFormatException caught here then `test` is string
        // NOT valid integer
        flag = true;
    }
    if (flag == false) {
        // Page Number is string
        // Use `test` variable here
    } else {
        // Page Number is integer
        // Use `pageNo` variable here
    }
```

Comment: test = test.replace("page", "");  is working fine but after that rest of part can be string or a int for example it can be "0003" or "MN23". so i can i differentiate it and store it in proper datatype variable and i have to use that single variable outside in code